# How to get domain from email address in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the domain part from an email address, in Javascript. It's easy to extract the domain from an email like via `split`: "joe@example.com", which is `example.com`.

However, emails also come in forms like "joe@subdomain1.example.com.uk", of which the domain is `example.com.uk`, instead of `subdomain1.example.com.uk`. The problem here is that `subdomain1` can be mistakenly considered as part of the domain.

How do I do this reliably?

Comment: No. This simplistic approach doesn't handle the second scenario I mentioned.

Comment: Well but then you need to know all the domains. This is simply not possible. How do you then know what a subdomain is or not.

Comment: Extracting a TLD from a subdomain is too broad, and needs special checks.

Comment: @31piy I have read that answer and I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 17):

That is really not a trivial problem as it might seem at first glance. 
Luckily there are libs that solves this, [tld-extract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tld-extract) is a popular choice which uses  Mozilla's Public Suffix List (a volunteer based list). The usage is

```
var parser = require('tld-extract');

console.log( parser("www.google.com") );
console.log( parser("google.co.uk") );
/**
* >> { tld: 'com', domain: 'google.com', sub: 'www' }
* >> { tld: 'co.uk', domain: 'google.co.uk', sub: '' }
*/
```

To extract the server address part from email address first split by `@` character like this

```
const email = "john@sub.domain.com"
const address = email.split('@').pop()
const domain = parser(address).domain
```

See more in depth discussion about the problem solution check the [README](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) of a similar python library.

> tldextract on the other hand knows what all gTLDs and ccTLDs look like
>   by looking up the currently living ones according to the Public Suffix
>   List (PSL). So, given a URL, it knows its subdomain from its domain,
>   and its domain from its country code.

Make sure to learn about the list on Public Suffix List [website](https://www.publicsuffix.org/learn/) and understand it is based on volunteer work and might not be exhaustive at all time.

> The Public Suffix List is a cross-vendor initiative to provide an
>   accurate list of domain name suffixes, maintained by the hard work of
>   Mozilla volunteers and by submissions from registries, to whom we are
>   very grateful.
>
> Since there was and remains no algorithmic method of finding the
>   highest level at which a domain may be registered for a particular
>   top-level domain (the policies differ with each registry), the only
>   method is to create a list. This is the aim of the Public Suffix List.

Comment: Only issue with this is it doesn’t work with email addresses.

Comment: I will edit my answer to mention it, thank you. For email address take the part after `@` and apply the same.

Comment: Only problem is that an email address _can_ have more than one `@` – so best take the _last_ `@` as a safeguard!

Comment: The problem also does not work for: user@gmail.com

Comment: I think the solution to the issue of it not working with emails is to add a prefix of `http://` at the beginning. That worked for me: `const address = 'http://' + email.split('@')[1]}`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the best solution for this problem would be to use a library, like what was suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893282/2735286.

Yet if you have a long enough list with top level domains and subdomains, you could write some code which extracts whatever characters are found after the '@' sign and then from the domain you try to find out whether you have a top level or subdomain. When you know if you are dealing with a top level domain you know where you can find the main domain name and so everything before it must be a subdomain. The same applies to the subdomain.

This is a naive implementation, but you could try this:

```js
// TODO: needs to have an exhaustive list of top level domains
const topLevelDomains = ["com", "org", "int", "gov", "edu", "net", "mil"];

// TODO: Needs an exhaustive list of subdomains
const subdomains = ["co.uk", "org.uk", "me.uk", "ltd.uk", "plc.uk"];

function extract(str) {
  const suffix = str.match(/.+@(.+)/);
  if (suffix) {
    const groups = suffix.pop().split(".");
    const lastPart = groups[groups.length - 1];
    if (isSubDomain(groups[groups.length - 2] + "." + lastPart)) {
      console.log("Sub domain detected in: " + groups);
      if (groups.length > 3) {
        console.log("Possible subdomain: " + groups.splice(0, groups.length - 3));
        console.log();
      }
    } else if (isTopLevelDomain(lastPart)) {
      console.log("Top level domain detected in: " + groups);
      if (groups.length > 2) {
        console.log("Possible subdomain: " + groups.splice(0, groups.length - 2));
        console.log();
      }
    }
  }
}

function isTopLevelDomain(lastPart) {
  return (topLevelDomains.find(s => s === lastPart));
}

function isSubDomain(lastPart) {
  return (subdomains.find(s => s === lastPart));
}

extract("joe@example.com");
extract("joe@subdomain1.example.co.uk");
extract("joe@subdomain2.example.edu");
extract("joe@subdomain3.example.ltd.uk");
extract("joe@test.subdomain3.example.plc.uk");
```

Please challenge the logic, if I got this wrong.

Answer (score -2):

```
// Not a proper solution because of email pattern is not fixed. Use below if it is appropriate solution according to your problem .

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    //var input = 'joe@subdomain1.com';
    var input = 'joe@subdomain1.example.com.uk';
    var first_split = input.split("@")[1];
    var second_split = first_split.split(".");
        if(second_split.length == 2) {

            console.log('domain is : '+first_split);

        } else if(second_split.length > 2) {
            var str = first_split.substring(first_split.indexOf(".") + 1);
            console.log('domain is : '+str);
        }


      });
```