# Check email domain type (personal email or company email)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, email, npm

Example

```
isPersonalEmail("name@gmail.com") // true
isPersonalEmail("name@companyName.com") // false
```

I can't find NPM package do that
I need to check email in node.js server

Answer (score 5):

I found two npm packages that you can use to achieve that:

### [Free Email Domains](https://github.com/Kikobeats/free-email-domains) by Kiko Beats

The package is based on [HubSpot-blocked domains](https://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms/what-domains-are-blocked-when-using-the-forms-email-domains-to-block-feature)

### [Email Providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-providers) by derhuerst

Provides the same solution, with the advantage of having the option to use all 4k domains in the list, or the **312 common domains** only. he defines common as follows:

> common.json contains those with an Majestic Million rank of < 100000.

---

## Full Solution

I also stumbled upon a [relevant issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49892932/3222120) that you might want to consider when you extract the domain.

```js
const emailProviders = require("email-providers/all.json")
const parser = require('tld-extract');
const validator = require('validator');

const companyEmail = "name@companyName.com"
const personalEmail = "name@gmail.com"
const personalEmailWithSubdomain = "name@abc.gmail.com"

// 1. You should validate that the string is an actual email as well
// if (!validator.isEmail(email)) return error or something...

const isPersonalEmail = (email) => {

    // 2. Extract the domain
    const broken = email.split('@')
    const address = `http://${broken[broken.length - 1]}`
    const { domain } = parser(address);

    // 3. And check!
    return emailProviders.includes(domain)
}

console.log(isPersonalEmail(companyEmail)) // false
console.log(isPersonalEmail(personalEmail)) // true
console.log(isPersonalEmail(personalEmailWithSubdomain)) // true
```